# Stream media file using asp.net core and azure cloudblob

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I want to create endpoint that will stream video stream that is stored in azure CloudBlob. Here is snippet of my code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideo(string videoId)
    {
        var videoStream = await _contentStorage.Get(videoId);

        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(videoStream, mimeType);
        fileStreamResult.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return fileStreamResult;
    }
```

and in ContentStorage

```
   public async Task<StoredContent> Get(string id)
    {
        var block = _blobContainer.GetBlobClient(id);
        var ms = await block.OpenReadAsync();
        return ms;
    }
```

I had everything working fine except iPhones and safari, after some debugging it turned out that my endpoint is returning 200 http code, but it should 206 - partial content. So I made some changes into my code, here is some snippet:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideo(string videoId)
    {
        var videoStream = await _contentStorage.Get(videoId);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await videoStream.CopyToAsync(ms);

        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(ms, mimeType);
        fileStreamResult.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return fileStreamResult;
    }
```

Now when I test it on iphone or by postman response is 206, and it's working fine. But I thing that copping the video stream into new memorystream is a valid approach.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I understand this code as for every partial of the video, I'm downloading whole video from blob storage, cut it and then return just the piece within range.

It's not sure for me how to handle this case, is there any out of the box solution for that, or do I need to read range header from request and use OpenReadAsync with parameters as position and buffer side? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me was to update Azure.Storage.Blobs library. I had 12.6.0 and after update to 12.7.0 it started working as expected, since they added:

[Added seekability to BaseBlobClient.OpenRead().](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/CHANGELOG.md)